Androidからペリフェラルすると、iPhoneから複数見えます。
Bluetooth LEのペリフェラルを、Java Android プログラムで作っています。
しかし、iPhoneから見ると、同じデバイスが複数回現れては消えて、を繰り返してしまいます。識別子が送られていないのかな？と思います。
たしかに、製品のベンダーとモデル番号しかキャラおくっていません。
これを、同一デバイスとさせたいのですが、なにを通信すればよいかご存じでないでしょうか？よろしくお願い致します。
意味が、と返信ありましたので、追記させていただきます。
追記１）
具体的には、
CHARACTERISTIC_BLE_MIDIには  {}0バイト配列をGATT_SUCCESSで返しています。
MODEL_NUMBERには、文字列をutf8で、GATT_SUCCESS。
MANUFACTURER_NAMEにも、utf8の文字列。
それ以外は{} 0バイト配列を返しています。
この場合、同じソフトが複数あるかないか判断できないですよね。
追記２）
SERIAN_NUMBERと、FIRMWARE_REVISION、HARDWARE_REVISIONを設定したのですが、
私のAndroidアプリは、iPhoneの、Bluetoothキャッシュ（MIDI）から消えてくれません。
MD-BT01は、電源を切ると消えます。どのような手続きが必要でしょうか。
追記３）
とりあえず、個人的には、下から読みすすめてまいります。
https://blog.reinforce-lab.com/post/2013-08-13-blebook-ch2-ble-spec/
この翻訳の元になる原文は2000ページのPDFらしいですね。
＃コメント欄はもう使わないでください。回答欄だけでお願いします。


Androidからペリフェラルすると、iPhoneから複数見えます。 これはどういうことでしょうか。意味不明です。（色々意味不明なところはありますが、まずはこれを）


こんな感じで、消滅したペリフェラルが、リストから消えないので、複数になります。https://x.com/synthtarou/status/1850570055718928439?s=46

ひょっとして、ペリフェラルの意味が分からないなんて事なんでしょうか？

ペリフェラルでぐぐればその意味が出てきます。で、あなたの言いたいペリフェラルというのはそれと一致してますか？あなた独自の用語を使っても、他人から見たら意味不明としか見えません。

例えば「電話する」は通じても「車する」とはあまり言いません (正確には車を "運転" する)。同じ理屈で「ペリフェラルする」も日本語表現としては不自然/不親切で、「ペリフェラルとして接続する」のように書くべきかと思います。

ペリフェラルでぐぐっても出てこないと思います。Bluetooth LE ペリフェラルなら出てくると思います。正式名称です。また「ペリフェラルとして接続する」ではなく「ペリフェラルとして待機する」になると思います。すいませんが、スレを荒らさないでいただきたい。

言い回しは大事だと思うのですが、こちらの表現の方が合っているのでは？ AndroidをBLEペリフェラルにしよう

ググればわかるのアカウントの人は答えわかりますか？

古くて更新されていないようですが、この辺のリポジトリが何か参考になるかも？ WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android, rwslinkman/SimDeviceBLE, vhiribarren/beacon-simulator-android

ありがたい。なるほど、でもなぜ回答ではなくコメント欄に？とりあえず見た感じstopAdvertisingの前後にあれ送るみたいな？バイト終わって帰宅したら検証してみますね。

それらは、そもそもペリフェラルを再起動していないですね。それから、コメント欄はもう使わないでください。回答欄だけでお願いしますね。

最終回答。
Googleのフォーラムみていたら、UUIDが、StartPeripheralごとに、ランダム生成されるらしく、それが原因でした。
それを問題と考えるコメントも多数ありました。Androidの仕様（とiPhoneのスキャンの仕様）なだけでした。
